# ReactJS - "setState" with react Hooks, does not merge the state but rather replaces it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have the following piece of logic, regarding a state with `useState` and a Websocket endpoint streaming data.

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ items: [], activity: [] });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const currentItems = R.isNil(data.items) ? [] : data.items;
    const currentActivity = R.isNil(data.activity) ? [] : data.activity;

    setState({
      ...state,
      items: Array.from(new Set([...state.items, ...currentItems])),
      activity: Array.from(new Set([...state.activity, ...currentActivity]))
    });
  }, [data]);

  console.log('State:', state); // This just replaces the state instead of merging.
```

But I cannot make the state to merge. It just replaces the state each time with a new value from the stream. What am I missing. I haven't used hooks that much, but it seems weird. `I am spreading the state, then updating, each value`. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "replaces"? If you mean they are not the same object, that's normal. The merged state should be an entirely new object, not the original object with mutations. Perhaps add the log from the console?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using a callback function in useState hook:

```
setState(prev =>{
  ...prev,
  items: Array.from(new Set([...prev.items, ...currentItems])),
  activity: Array.from(new Set([...prev.activity, ...currentActivity]))
});
```